# How to skip execution of task or container based on condition?

Tags: ssis

I have a couple of sequential control flow task and containers.

I have seen that there is an expression property called disable using which I can dynamically disable a task or container.

Instead of disabling and stopping the workflow, How can I skip a task or container but continue executing from the immediate next control flow task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequence Containers allow for the logical grouping of tasks. I make heavy use of them in my packages.

Disabling a Task or Container, simply causes execution to bypass it. Here I have the Disabled property set to True on "Sequence Container 1" and you can see the green checks are showing for "Sequence Container" and "Sequence Container 2"

[image]

If I wanted to disable a whole downstream path, I would modify the precedence constraint  between "Sequence Container" and "Sequence Container" to be "Expression and Constraint" and then have an Expression, based on a variable, like `@[User::ProcessingReady]`

[image]

There, you can see that 1 & 2 are enabled, but they did not get a green check during processing because the criteria for continuing, the precedent constraint (fx) was not satisfied.

### Addressing comments

"When the disable is done based on an expression on the task (in properties pane), then also does it behave in same way like right click and disable task? The first being dynamic method and later manual method."

Exactly! How the Task got into a Disabled state does not matter, the behaviour will be the same: it does not execute and the next, enabled, task in line runs.

The image below shows a task that is disabled via an Expression - the fx in the upper left corner provides a visual cue to the expression's existence.

[image]

Comment: When the disable is done based on an expression on the task (in properties pane), then also does it behave in same way like right click and disable task? The first being dynamic method and later manual method.

Comment: Bingo. Updated my answer with your comment answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Double Click the data flow path arrow and set a precedent constraint (fx)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/precedence-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15